# The number of real roots of $e^x = x^2 $ .

Tags: real-analysis, functions, exponential-function, roots, transcendental-equations

The number of real roots of $e^x = x^2 $ .

According to me, it should me zero. But the answer says its one.

How to proceed.

Comment: Hint:  sketch the two graphs $y=e^x$ and $y=x^2$.

Comment: Consider $e^x - x^2 = 0$. Use the intermediate value theorem to conclude that there is some solution for $x < 0$.

Comment: "According to me, it should me zero" What would be interesting, and would transform this into a question with context, would be to know how you came to the conclusion that the number of real roots is zero.

Comment: @BarryCipra  According to graphs there are two solutions. But we only need the real ones.

Comment: @user371530, I don't understand your comment.  The two graphs should clearly show an intersection with $x\lt0$.  Depending on how loosely you sketch them, they might show the parabola crossing the exponential for some $x\gt0$, which needs to be ruled out.  (I was really only concerned with showing that you can't have *zero* real roots.)  In any event, sketching the graphs can only indicate where real roots occur, so I don't understand your second sentence at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x) = e^x - x^2$, then $f'(x) = e^x - 2x$ and $f''(x) = e^x - 2$. $f''(x) = 0$ at $x = \ln(2)$ , and so $f'(x) \geq f'(\ln(2)) = 2 - 2 \ln(2)$. Since $2 < e$ we have $f'(x) > 0$ everywhere.

Thus the function either has 0 roots or 1 root. Since $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = - \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ we see it has one root.

Answer (score 0):

$(1)\enspace x>0$ : $\enspace x^{\frac{1}{x}}=\sqrt{e}>\max(x^{\frac{1}{x}})=e^{\frac{1}{e}}\enspace $ => no solution

$(2)\enspace y:=-x$ with $y>0$ : $\enspace y^{\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}<1\enspace $ => one solution

With $(1)+(2)$ follows: one solution